# ng-change directive on a dropdown that affects that class of another HTML element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the below HTML.  Based on male or female, I want the icon to the left of the input to change.  The problem is that when it is first changed to female from nothing, it does not change (however, the ng-change function is called and works as expected) but the class does not update until it's switched again.

```
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-male fa-lg fa-fw" ng-class="genderIcon"></i></span>
<select id="gender" name="gender" class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="form.gender" ng-change="switchGender()">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Gender</option>
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>
```

And here is the `switchGender` function:

```
$scope.switchGender = function() {
    $scope.genderIcon = ($scope.form.gender == 'Male') ? 'fa-male' : 'fa-female';
    console.log($scope.genderIcon);
}
```

The correct class is logged to the console but is not represented in the view.  Why is it not updating immediately in the view regardless of the icon variable being correct?

Answer (score 1):

Use good directive provided by angular `ng-class`, apply it on UI directly.

Whenever you write a `ng-class` directive, angular internally create a watcher for it, Whenever any scope variable gets updated this watcher gets called and the the expression inside the `ng-class` will get evaluated on each digest cycle & the resultant class applied to `class` attribute of that element.

**HTML**

```
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw" ng-class="{form.gender == 'Male' ? 'fa-male' : 'fa-female'}"></i></span>
<select id="gender" name="gender" class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="form.gender" ng-change="switchGender()">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Gender</option>
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/oWgKnR4whfk1biVm6mp5?p=preview)

Hope this will solve your problem. Thanks.

Comment: This does not even change it at all.

Comment: I switched out my conditional statement (like you have here) in the ng-class.

Comment: I switched it to this: `{'fa-male': form.gender == 'Male', 'fa-female': form.gender == 'Female'}`.  But, it still only works on the second switch.

Comment: I know, you had ng-ng-class...  I didn't use that, I used just ng-class.  And that does not work as expected.

Comment: @NoahMatisoff did you look at my answer? Does it helped you?